# correctly terminate boost::asio::ip::tcp::accept (Linux)

Tags: c++, boost, synchronous

I wonder how to implement a synchronous socket accept with boost which can be terminated.

To demonstrate my problem I slightly modified the [synchonous tcp echo example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp).

*Note: the provided code seems to be working on Windows platforms but i'm having problems on a Linux machine.*

Let's say the server receives a quit message and now wants to terminate an endless loop which accepts new connections.
Most tutorials etc. recommend you to run acceptor->close() in this case. But as
[this post](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/tcp-acceptor-works-differently-on-windows-than-linux-td2587713.html) states, the results might be undefined if `close()` is called from another thread.

If you do so, `accept()` won't terminate this time but when another client tries to connect it returnes an error (on Linux!)

So my question again: how do I correctly terminate a server which is based on `boost::asio` which continuously synchronously accepts connections?

Here the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void session(boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> sock, tcp::acceptor *acceptor )
{
    try {
        for (;;) {

            char data[ 1024 ];

            boost::system::error_code error;
            size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof) { break; }
            else if (error) { throw boost::system::system_error(error); }

            if( std::string("quit") == data ) {    // TRY TO CANCEL THE ACCEPT
                acceptor->close();
                break;
            }
            boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(data, length));
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) { std::cerr << "exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n"; }
}

void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
{
    tcp::acceptor a( io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port) );
    for (;;) {
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> sock(new tcp::socket(io_service));
        boost::system::error_code error;
        a.accept( *sock, error );

        if( !error ) {
            boost::thread t( boost::bind( session, sock, &a ) );
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "acceptor canceled "<< error << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try{
        // ..check args here...

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        server(io_service, std::atoi(argv[1]));
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to cancel a synchronous `accept` from `boost::asio`.  Can you refactor this to use `async_accept()` instead?  (The answer is of course, yes -- but it may be some work if your actual code isn't trivial as in this example).

Comment: Yes. Why would you ever do blocking socket calls? To go through the horror of a threaded application for the added fun of trying to cancel synchronous operations? Do it all with non-blocking sockets, surely. If you insist, you need to set a timer on your accept() call (eg SIGALARM) and check a flag each loop. 50ms alarms means the main thread never has to wait more than 50ms until the cancellation is processed.